# Prevent "c from becoming ç (Babel Spanish)

Tags: babel, accents

I am writing the user manual of an R function. For the arguments of the function I need some quotes, and I'd like them to be square quotes, just like the ones the user will find when actually using the function.

For most of the arguments the quotes work well, but I'm stuck with one of them:

`functionName(argument1 = "calories", argument2)`

The `"c` part of it is rendered as **ç**, giving me **çalories"** instead of **"calories"**.

What I have tried:

- `functionName(argument1 = \"calories", argument2)`. This renders **c̈alories"**.
- `functionName(argument1 = ""calories", argument2)`. This renders **calories"**.
- `functionName(argument1 = """calories", agument2)`. This renders **çalories"** again.

I've unsuccessfully tried some other combinations.

How can I escape the `"c` sequence and have **both** the square quotes and the c?

### EDIT (adding a MWE)

```
\documentclass[oneside,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\title{title}
\author{author}

\newenvironment{alltypewritter}{\ttfamily}{\par}
         
\begin{document}

%\maketitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{alltypewritter}
  functionName(argument1 = "calories",\\
  \hphantom{functionName(} argument2)
  
\end{alltypewritter}

\end{document}
```

[image: This is how it renders]

Comment: How are you typing `functionName...`? Is it in an environment? Is it just plain text? For example, I would probably show code using a verbatim environment, and doing `\verb|functionName(argument1 = "calories", argument2)|` would print fine.

Comment: It would help if you include a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) showing what you are doing and what you've tried. This makes it easier for others to provide a solution that fits with your needs/requirements.

Comment: @WillieWong I defined an environment ```\newenvironment{alltypewritter}{\ttfamily}{\par}``` and I'm typing the function inside it: ```\begin{alltypewritter} functionName...\end{alltypewritter}```

Comment: There is something else you are not sharing with us. If I put `\documentclass{article}` followed by your `\newenviornment` definition, I get no problems with the double quote symbol (it just works). So please, edit your file to include a MWE as I mentioned above.

Comment: It's `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` what causes the wrong behaviour. If I use English, it just works. How can I avoid babel converting the `"c` sequence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use `shorthands=off`, like so:

```
\documentclass[oneside,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[shorthands=off,spanish]{babel}
\newenvironment{alltypewritter}{\ttfamily}{\par}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alltypewritter}
        functionName(argument1 = "calories",\\
    \end{alltypewritter}
\end{document}
```

I use it routinely with German lest I go crazy.

Answer (score 9):

I would advocate using a verbatim environment `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` or something like the [listings](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings?lang=en) package to typeset code.

But if you are happy with your own solution, you can turn off the babel shorthands locally:

`\newenvironment{alltypewritter}{\shorthandoff{"}\ttfamily}{\par}`

will turn off the double-quote short hand used by babel inside your environment.

Comment: I'm getting this: `! Package babel Error: I can't switch '"' on or off--not a shorthand.`

Comment: I'll go with your recommendation of using a verbatim environment, thanks.

Comment: Hmmm. Using TeXLive 2022 on Overleaf switching the shorthand on and off works just fine, and the `\shorthandon/off` macros have been in existence for at least 10 years. So I have no idea why you are getting that error.

Comment: It seems wrong to unconditionally enable shorthand at the end of the environment; it should instead restore the mode in effect before the environment disabled it.

Comment: @BenVoigt: actually, that `\shorthandon` has zero effect, because of grouping. Let me delete that. (I just realized it when I read your comment.)

Answer (score 5):

You want to locally disable shorthands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\newenvironment{alltypewritter}{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}%
  \raggedright
  \ttfamily
}{\par\addvspace{\topsep}}

% " is a babel shorthand for Spanish, maybe others are needed
\AtBeginEnvironment{alltypewritter}{\shorthandoff{"}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alltypewritter}
  functionName(argument1 = "calories",\\
  \hphantom{functionName(}argument2)
\end{alltypewritter}

\end{document}
```

I left the environment name as in the question, but “typewriter” has no double “t”.

[image]

As suggested in comments, you may have better output with `verbatim`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
functionName(argument1 = "calories",
             argument2)
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Look at the `fancyvrb` package for more features in verbatim text.

Answer (score 3):

As others said, you can disable shorthands. A simple shorthand to disable only a specific accidental `"c` shorthand, worth the redundancy, is avoid have the two characters really glued together with `"{}c`. To disable automatically the shorthand to avoid this kind of accidents, you can use the babel options, but if you are using other languages, it could be better disable specifically only the  Spanish shorthands, with `es-noshorthands` option:

```
\documentclass[oneside,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}
\newenvironment{alltypewritter}{\ttfamily}{\par}
\begin{document}
\begin{alltypewritter}
  functionName(argument1 = "calories",\\
  \hphantom{functionName(} argument2)
\end{alltypewritter}
\end{document}
```

But if you are an R user, it is almost a crime no dot take advantage of R with `knitr` to show R code, and not only because this obviates the issue without deactivating shorthands:

```
% mwe.Rnw (in Rstudio)
% mwe.Rtex (in Overleaf)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
<<test,eval=F>>=
functionName(argument1 = "calories",
             argument2)
@
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The use of {knitr} is indeed an interesting point of view. By the way, I tried to edit `{knitr}` as it has a typo, but my edit is only one character, and I really didn't want to mess with anything else.

Comment: @PavoDive Typo fixed, thanks.